# javascript regex replace spaces between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use JS regex to replace all occurences of a space with the word SPACE, if between brackets?
So, what I want is this:

```
myString = "a scentence (another scentence between brackets)"
myReplacedString = myString.replace(/*some regex*/)
//myReplacedString is now "a scentence (anotherSPACEscentenceSPACEbetweenSPACEbrackets)"
```

EDIT:
what I've tried is this (I'm quite new to regular expressions)

```
myReplacedString = myString.replace(/\(\s\)/, "SPACE");
```

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [help])

Comment: I'd use [`let res = input.replace(/\s+(?=[^)(]*\))/g, "");`](https://tio.run/##HcvLCoMwEEbhvU/x42qmF90WgvRBtMVpHKQlNDIJef00dHcW3/lIkeTtfeRrudUaNCNlw4RVQC94bIx/oTU2KK@uK2IwTU01O5geQbzSuKQz3af5yfQ4LczjfkHfs@t8/KYYdAhxp7axq/UH) on shorter strings and the callback `let res = str.replace(/\([^)(]*\)/g, m => m.replace(/\s+/g, ""));` for large strings or with a lot of whitespaces inside.

Comment: If the parentheses are *nested*, it could be done [by parsing (JS demo)](https://tio.run/##XVFBasMwELzrFZOTJYzjtL0UhB/QW6HXHmKUdesiJOOVc2nydndlO6HtwiJmNaOZRV/tuWU39kOqzs/z7CmhD8OU0OAYp8T9iaD9QfrBYD2lHyGl/ZMx5nZj8JuOm0SAcKTkFkerVF2Dk/iBh9aRmC2aQJzohKEdKaRPYmLVTcGlPoaV/pbZ/BJetUCjvpVYSNaRWJIWhd1wHCjI4JBxF0doFwMnOMQOixDIUqm@0w6NaHVh1gkWdVnaFZJniddho5m/tKraaPfXdov35YJd/c71PslG2pm7KCctG7gsu6qM0zSGPLbqqtS6yL9Vl58wVuUloqe9jx9aiMbO8w8).

Answer (score 6):

You could perhaps use the regex:

```
/\s(?![^)]*\()/g
```

This will match any space without an opening bracket ahead of it, with no closing bracket in between the space and the opening bracket.

Here's a [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/mB1nH5).

EDIT: I hadn't considered cases where the sentences don't end with brackets. The regexp of @thg435 covers it, however:

```
/\s(?![^)]*(\(|$))/g
```

Comment: I'd say `/\s(?![^)]*(\(|$))/`, to handle something like `xx (xx xx) xx xx`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about one regex, but you can use two.  One to get the string inside the `()`, then another to replace `' '` with `'SPACE'`.

```
myReplacedString = myString.replace(/(\(.*?\))/g, function(match){
    return match.replace(/ /g, 'SPACE');
});
```